# Application Not Starting with Java.Mail API

Tags: java

I'm trying to send emails through my application. However, there is a problem. Whenever I create a method that has this code

```
public void sendEmail() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("username","password");
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@no-spam.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("to@no-spam.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
                "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The application just won't start. Even when I'm not calling the sendEmail(); method. However, if I comment out the whole method, my application can be ran from the build .jar file without any problems.

However, I noticed if I run the application through Intellij, and the method is being called, it'll work just fine, and I can send out the email.

Comment: Rather than `throw new RuntimeException(e);` how about just printing (and telling us) what the exception is

Comment: @ScaryWombat I can't debug the application itself. However, when debugging through Intellij, I don't get any errors, and it works just fine.

Comment: What's your build system? Maven? Gradle? Something else? What **exactly** happens when you attempt to run your application? How **exactly** are you running it?

Comment: missing activation.jar?

Comment: @giorgiga I don't have Activation.jar Not sure where to get it. I did google it, but found only 1 result that was accurate, but seemed sketchy.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Okay, I tried debugging it using cmd, and I keep getting this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address
        at Theminis.AccountsFormat.main(AccountsFormat.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Address
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more

Comment: so that jar is not on the classpath

Comment: @ScaryWombat Seems like it. However, I checked my manifest, and I had the class path of the library Java.Mail.jar like so: Class-Path: Java.Mail.jar. 

However, this method has worked. If I put the library Java.Mail.jar and my main .jar file together in 1 folder, and run the main jar file, it works. How should I go about merging them together into 1 .jar file?

Comment: Never mind, I've fixed it after playing around with the libraries etc. I had to extract the library into my project so it compiles with it.